# Передача по ссылке - тождественна ли передаче указателя?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, указатели, dll, ссылки

Читал не раз, что передача по ссылке - это просто передача указателя, который внутри функции автоматически разыменовывается. Насколько это верно?

Например, я написал такую dll (в Visual Studio):

```
extern "C"
void __declspec(dllexport) test(int* i)
{
    cout << "test(" << *i << ")\n";
    (*i)++;
}
```

И вот такую программу для работы с ней:

```
typedef void (*myfunc)(int&);
int main()
{
    HMODULE dll;
    if ((dll = LoadLibrary("Dll.dll")) != NULL)
    {
        myfunc f = (myfunc)GetProcAddress(dll,"test");
        int q = 5;
        cout << "q = " << q << endl;
        f(q);
        cout << "q = " << q << endl;
        FreeLibrary(dll);
    }
}
```

Все работает, получается что я и хотел:

```
q = 5
test(5)
q = 6
```

Только насколько на эту передачу по ссылке как указателя можно полагаться? Какие могут быть неприятности?

И еще сразу хотел спросить, у меня, например, в dll используется `cout` - это тот же `cout`, что и в основной программе или нет? А если я передам на него указатель - то все равно ведь будет использоваться код в dll, а не в программе? Или если я выделю в dll память, то как ее правильно освободить в программе? например, если я верну `unique_ptr` в функции в dll?

Comment: Отличия могут возникнуть при передаче классов.

Comment: Это почти всегда верно с точки зрения внутренней реализации. Это, однако, совсем не означает, что вы имеете право объявить функцию с параметром-ссылкой, а определить - с параметром-указателем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Нет, не тождественна.**

Указатель - это физический объект в памяти, **занимающий** место и умеющий значение.

Ссылка - это просто *синоним* имени объекта, для хранения которого не выделяется дополнительной памяти.

Другими словами, когда Вы оперируете ссылками, то можете представить что работаете с той же переменной, что и при объявлении (для компилятора нет разницы в этом случае).

---

В случае использования динамически подключаемых библиотек, строгой рекомендацией является использование *С интерфейса* (в С существуют только указатели), дабы иметь возможность работать с библиотекой из других языков. Не стоит в данном случае возвращать std::unique_ptr<>.

Также насчёт выделения памяти, если Вы выделяете память **внутри** библиотеки, то **внутри** и должны освобождать.

Использование умных указателей в данном случае - современный подход слежения за памятью. Старайтесь строго избегать явных вызовов `delete`.

Прежде всего стоит определиться нужно действительно нужно ли выделять память внутри библиотеки или допустимо передать ей буфер и его размер.

---

Если всё же библиотеке нужно выделять память и возвращать её, то допустим мы имеем две функции:

`void* dll_alloc(size_t size)` и `dll_free(void* ptr)`

Тогда для удобной работы и автоматическим освобождением памяти, можем использовать следующее:

`std::shared_ptr<void> dllMemory(dll_alloc(1024), dll_free);`

В таком случае, нам не нужно явно вызывать `dll_free`.

Answer (score 6):

Вы не имеете права предполагать, что ссылка внутри устроена как указатель. Декларация функции, отличающаяся от её настоящего определения, есть undefined behaviour.

То, что это «работает» — случайность, как и при любом UB. С усложнением программы и/или изменением настроек компилятора возможны любые неприятные сюрпризы.

---

То, что в приведённых вами словах верно — это то, что ссылка *ведёт себя* во многом как автоматически разыменуемый указатель.

Важное семантическое отличие между указателем и ссылкой — ссылку нельзя переназначить, и она обязательно указывает на какой-то объект (в корректной программе). То есть, не существует «null-ссылок».

Comment: Так что, как я понял, нужно просто не рисковать? )

Comment: @Mikhailo: Ну да, тем более, это явно запрещено стандартом.

Answer (score 4):

По первой части - думаю, что в стандарте никаких указаний нет и не должно быть. Откровенно говоря, не думаю, что если такая передача в VC++ получается успешно, то в какой-то момент перестанет быть таковой... но вполне допускаю, что другой компилятор может работать и иначе. Поэтому, как мне кажется, в пределах одного компилятора - грубо говоря, в своей программе - пользоваться в принципе можно... отдавая отчет в том, что теоретически это может сломаться в каких-то будущих версиях.

Но не проще ли использовать лишний уровень косвенности? Просто написать функцию-посредник, принимающую ссылку, но вызывающую функцию DLL с передачей ей адреса этой ссылки?

По второй части - если вы использовали статические библиотеки, то да, `cout` у вас разные, если же динамический runtime - то, думаю, один и тот же, из динамических библиотек.

По поводу памяти - насколько я помню советы опытных :), крайне желательно освобождать память там, где она была выделена. Но как с этим согласовать те же интеллектуальные указатели или что-то иное - простой и надежный способ в голову пока не приходит.

Comment: Освобождать память можно где угодно, главное — чтобы в тот heap, в котором она была выделена. То есть, `delete` должно вести в тот же рантайм, что и `new` (что в случае DLL не само собой разумеется). Смарт-пойнтер должен по идее помочь, он инкапсулирует `delete` (но я не уверен на все 100%).

Comment: Хотя, передача смарт-пойнтера через границы DLL наверное не лучшая идея.

Comment: @VladD Меня этот вопрос заинтересовал, я немного покрутил, но... Вобщем, если вы скажете что-то умное в ответ на мой [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/636454/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-dll-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b5%d0%b5?s=1|0.0000) - буду признателен :)

Comment: А насколько - будучи собранным одним компилятором, но со статической линковкой рантайма - рантаймы в DLL и в EXE можно рассматривать как одинаковые? У них же какие-то свои внутренние переменные, как я понимаю, разные?

Comment: Написал в ответе на ваш вопрос.