# Работа с DLL от Visual C++ из Open Watcom

Tags: windows, visual-c++, dll

Пытаюсь научиться работать с DLL, созданной в VC++ (x86, 32 бита) из другого компилятора (конкретно для экспериментов взял Open Watcom, тоже 32 бита). Что-то не очень получается.

Что есть: простейшая DLL

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void test1()
    {
        std::cout << "sizeof(int*) = " << sizeof(int*) << "\n";
        std::cout << "test1\n";
    }
    __declspec(dllexport) void test2(int i)
    {
        std::cout << "test2(" << i << ")\n";
    }
    __declspec(dllexport) int test3(int*p)
    {
        std::cout << "test3(" << p << ")\n";
        return ++(*p);
    }
}
```

Компилиреем как `cl /EHsc /LD /MT dll.cpp`, получаем `dll.dll` и `dll.lib`.

Два варианта работы из VC++ вполне работоспособны:

```
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllimport) void test1();
    __declspec(dllimport) void test2(int i);
    __declspec(dllimport) int test3(int*p);
}
int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    test1();
    test2(i);
    std::cout << test3(&i) << "\n";
    std::cout << test3(&i) << "\n";
}
```

с компиляцией как `cl /EHsc /MT use1.cpp dll.lib`

Второй вариант с динамическим подключением:

```
typedef void (*test1_func)();
typedef void (*test2_func)(int);
typedef int  (*test3_func)(int*);

int main()
{
    HMODULE dll;
    if ((dll = LoadLibrary("Dll.dll")) != NULL)
    {

        test1_func test1 = (test1_func)GetProcAddress(dll,"test1");
        test2_func test2 = (test2_func)GetProcAddress(dll,"test2");
        test3_func test3 = (test3_func)GetProcAddress(dll,"test3");

        int i = 5;
        test1();
        test2(i);
        std::cout << test3(&i) << "\n";
        std::cout << test3(&i) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Компилирую как `cl /EHsc /MT use2.cpp`. Тоже работает без нареканий.

В Watcom первый вариант - статическую линковку - я сделать так и не смог. то он ищет `_imp_test1`, то `test1`. Как ему пояснить, что я хочу, не знаю.

Динамическая компоновка проходит, но работать с указателем отказывается - сваливается с ошибкой обращения к памяти.

Думаю, что та же ерунда будет и при использовании других, отличных от VC++ компиляторов.

Подскажите, в чем я ошибся, и как корректно работать с DLL от VC++ из других компиляторов. Ведь как я понимаю, в Windows все DLL именно такие, от VC++. И как-то же их используют.

На всякий случай, [вопрос от Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/636454/228791) и ответы на него я читал (собственно, код примера частично на его остнове и сделан), но здесь же я просто обращаюсь к месту в памяти, а не работаю с менеджером?

Comment: Cоглашение о вызовах указывайте правильно.

Comment: __declspec - это атрибут, специфичный для Visual C++. Другие компиляторы не обязаны его понимать. Нужно курить документацию Watcom, что является его заменой. По второму способу - попробуйте прогнать dll через `dumpbin /exports` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference?view=msvc-170). Крайне вероятно, что там вместо "test1" будет "_test1" или что-то в этом роде.

Comment: @user7860670 Подскажите, как именно? что у меня не так? Разве `extern "C"` недостаточно?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Этот атрибут указывается только при сборке DLL, но не при попытках ее использовать.

Comment: `extern "C"` не достаточно. Если уж используете экзотические компиляторы, типа Watcom, то следует еще озаботиться соглашением о вызове. Выясните, какое соглашение он использует (stdcall, fastcall или еще что) и указывайте его при сборке. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gd-gr-gv-gz-calling-convention?view=msvc-170

Comment: Ну __declspec(dllimport) вы должны указывать при использовании DLL. Если вы этого не сделаете, раннее связывание не заработает и в Visual C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как выяснил путем экспериментов, все работает, если добавить к каждой функции `cdecl`... Спасибо за намеки в комментариях!